# cakephp 3.0 passing data to the form.php

Tags: cakephp

I am using a modelless form to send a contact email. I am using the example in the cookbook.

With the change to data in objects form arrays I am unsure what form the data is in being passed to the ContactForm.php

I have tried `$data['name']` and `$data[0]['name']`

View for input name without the data[]

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" required="" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
```

PagesController.php

```
public function contact(){

    $this->request->allowMethod('ajax');

    $contact = new ContactForm();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($contact->execute($this->request->data)) {
            $data = array(
                'status' => 'successful'
            );
        } else {
            $data = array(
                'status' => 'error'
            );
        }
        $this->set(compact('data')); // Pass $data to the view
        $this->set('_serialize', 'data');
    }

}
```

ContactForm.php

```
protected function _execute(array $data)
{
    // Send an email.
    $email = new Email('default');
    $email->emailFormat('html');
    $email->template('demoTemplate')->viewVars( array('userName' => $data[0]['name'],
        'userCompany' => '$data',
        'userEmail' => '$data',
        'userPhone' => '$data'));

    $email->from('info@domain.com');
    $email->to('$data');
    $email->bcc('$data');
    $email->subject('Contact Form Submission');
    if ($email->send()) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you simply do `pr($data)` or `var_dump($data)`, to see the structure?

Comment: By the way, you are calling `execute()`, while the function name is `_execute()`

Comment: I couldn't do a 'var_dump($data)' easily as I am sending the data with a ajax

Comment: `$contact->execute` I copied the code directly form the cookbook, I did notice that too but I did not question it http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/form.html

Comment: You can still do `var_dump` and put the output into a log, for example :)

Comment: Ok, you are extending form, I didn't know that. Sorry!

Comment: What are you trying to do? Passing default values? Use $this->request->data then as documented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for do this I use first this tool [advanced-rest-client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo), and inside the code of cakephp you can use try and catch, you can user `debug()` too, example `debug($data);` in combination with advanced-rest-client you can see the result.

and if debug dont work serialice the data

```
$this->set('data', $data);
$this->set('_serialize', ['data']);
```

but even when serialized data use advanced-rest-client, just select the `post` option and type the url of where you want to get the `post`.

**so:**

```
public function contact(){

  $this->request->allowMethod('ajax');

  $contact = new ContactForm();
  if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    if ($contact->execute($this->request->data)) {
        debug($this->request->data());//first 
        $datos = $this->request->data();//second 
        $data = [
          'content' => $datos,
          'status' => 'successful',
        ];
    } else {
        $datos = $this->request->data();
        $data = [
          'content' => $datos,
          'status' => 'error,
        ];
    }
    $this->set(compact('data')); // Pass $data to the view
    $this->set('_serialize', 'data');
  }
}
```